# Querying JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have parsed the JSON with json.load.
Now I want to query that JSON dict using SQL-like commands. Does anything exist like this in Python? I tried using Pynq https://github.com/heynemann/pynq but that didn't work too well and I've also looked into Pandas but not sure if that's what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple pandas example with Python 2.7 to get you started...

```
import json
import pandas as pd

jsonData = '[ {"name": "Frank", "age": 39}, {"name": "Mike", "age": 
18}, {"name": "Wendy", "age": 45} ]'

# using json.loads because I'm working with a string for example

d = json.loads(jsonData)

# convert to pandas dataframe

dframe = pd.DataFrame(d)

# Some example queries

# calculate mean age
mean_age = dframe['age'].mean()

# output - mean_age
# 34.0

# select under 40 participants
young = dframe.loc[dframe['age']<40]

# output - young
#   age   name
#0   39  Frank
#1   18   Mike


# select Wendy from data
wendy = dframe.loc[dframe['name']=='Wendy']

# output - wendy
#    age   name
# 2   45  Wendy
```

Comment: My issue now is that I've got a bunch of nested JSON. I've parsed them into dictionaries. How do I access those inner structures? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you could post a specific JSON string example of the problem you are working through and the result you are looking for and re-post as a new question that would be best. You are likely to get a very fast response.